# Time Series representation and forecasting in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have to forecast a time series in R of a Internet network traffic bitrate.
The data are in file http://www.forumaltavilla.it/joomla/datitesi/dati.dat and the sampling time is every 0.05 seconds.
Now, i want to use HoltWinters forecasting. My problem is setting the parameter deltat. On the Internet i saw deltat is the number of samples in a year but in this case deltat=1.58443823e-9 (0.05 seconds in years). Is it true or i should set deltat=0.05?

This is my script.

```
deltat=0.05
dati.ts=ts(scan("dati.dat", deltat),start=0,deltat)
model=HoltWinters(dati.ts)
dati.forecast=forecast(model,h=100)
plot(dati.forecast)
```

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is correct. Your units for `dati.ts` is seconds, and your delta is every 0.05 seconds. Just keep everything in seconds and don't try to do anything in years.

Note that the help for `ts` (obtained by `?ts`) doesn't mention years or months. As it says, if you use a frequency of 4 or 12, display methods will assume quarterly or monthly data, respectively, but that has nothing to do with the actual internal representation or what you can do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Holt-Winters forecasting would appear in my opinion to be inapplicable.[image] . It would appear that there have been significant effects that need to be be treated. You might consider a mixed-frequency model that might include second effects (20 readings per second) ; minute effects (1200 readings per minute). Your data covers two minutes which would be too short to seriously unravel the effect of minutes. The ACF [image] suggests both short term structure ( AR(1) and some "seasonal structure" that might be anywhere from 20-29.